# setXY function of node not setting xy position as 0,0

Tags: javascript, dom, yui3

I have to make a div appear right next to an input box, but this div is directly under the body unlike the input box which is under many divs.

So the scenario is I have many inputs, and I want to show some error in this div content. I check the content entered on blur, then whichever input on which blur happened, I take the position of this input box, setXY position of my div, and unhide it.

The code:

```
var input=Y.one("#input1");
var errorDiv=Y.one('#errorDiv');

input.on('blur',function(e){
  var xy=input.getXY();
  errorDiv.setXY([xy[0]+30,xy[1]]);
  errorDiv.removeClass('hide');
});
```

The problem I am facing is that setXY doesn't work the first time. Only after I change my focus the second time does the setXY put the correct position.
During debugging, I found that after this statement `errorDiv.setXY([xy[0]+30,xy[1]]);`, the xy position of error div is still 0,0.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I hope I am not the only that thought the title said seXY function....

Comment: You are not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to swap the order in which you handle the `errorDiv`'s appearance. So instead of setting a position then unhiding, try unhiding the div, then altering its position.

Simply change *this:*

```
  errorDiv.setXY([xy[0]+30,xy[1]]);
  errorDiv.removeClass('hide');
```

to **this.**

```
  errorDiv.removeClass('hide');
  errorDiv.setXY([xy[0]+30,xy[1]]);
```

I've created a [demo](http://jsbin.com/Itecama/1) demonstrating this change.

I have encountered this issue before, and I'm not *entirely* sure why it occurs, since I haven't delved too deeply into it, but my theory is that it has something to do with requiring the element to be visible first for a proper co-ordinate calculation. Hope this helps.